# Why do httpd and mysqld processes not show up in Activity Monitor?

Tags: apache, mysql, activity-monitor, macos

I'm running Mountain Lions built in Apache2 server. I have started the server and I can see the web pages but I can't see any httpd process in the Activity Monitor. Same goes for MySQL. I can't see mysqld process in it either.

I used MAMP before and those processes where shown in the Activity Monitor.

I can run the following command in terminal to list all processes in a text file. httpd and mysqld processes are showing up there.

`ps -A > process.txt`

Why the Activity Monitor is not showing these processes?

Comment: Choose _All Processes_ form the dropdown in Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 4):

In Activity Monitor there is a dropdown menu in the top of the window. *My Processes* was selected. Changing it to *All Processes* solved the issue.